# Ansible for ios network_cli - how do I auth with username and password?

Tags: ansible

Here's my playbook, getting an authentication failed message (yes my creds are correct)

```
---
- name: CHECK VERSION
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    creds:
      hosts: all
      username: "{{ ios_username }}"
      password: "{{ ios_password }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ios_username"
      prompt: "Your Username"
      private: no
    - name: "ios_password"
      prompt: "Your Password"
      private: yes


  tasks:
    - name: RUN SHOW VERSION  
      connection: network_cli
      ios_command:
        provider: "{{ creds }}"
        commands: show version
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

I'd really prefer not to enable ssh key auth for these devices, or any, so as to allow auditing of user actions.  Is there a way to pass my credentials using a playbook?

Answer (score 1):

I think your trouble is because you are using the `network_cli` connection but also using the `ios_command: provider`. This is redundant and will be confusing. Just use `network_cli` as `provider` is being deprecated. If you use the `network_cli` connection you need to pass those variables in to the `network_cli` plugin vars listed [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/network_cli.html).

```
ansible_user: "{{ ios_username }}" 
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ios_password }}"
```